# Getting started with deegree using Docker

Tags: workspace, docker, deegree

I'm trying to do the Getting Started tutorial using docker, but I can not import any workspaces (in tutorial step [3.1.1](https://download.deegree.org/documentation/current/html/#anchor-downloading-workspaces))

I installed the deegree server by the following steps:

1. Installed Docker for Windows
2. Run the commands described on [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/deegree/deegree3-docker/)

```
docker pull deegree/deegree3-docker:latest
docker run --name deegree -d -p 8080:8080 deegree/deegree3-docker
```

3. Run the steps from Getting Started tutorial (change to workspaces tab and click on import button for importing an official workspace)

When I try to import a workspace, I get the error message

> Unable to import workspace: Download of
> 'https://repo.deegree.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=releases&g=org.deegree&a=deegree-workspace-inspire&v=3.4.17&e=deegree-workspace' failed. Server responded with HTTP status code 404

I tried to figure out where the workspaces are stored but wasn't successful.

Comment: I've changed the title to make it plain you are trying to get deegree working here, and its not docker itself you are struggling with. Not sure why the close votes from people but maybe that...

Comment: Maybe your docker container doesn't have any network interfaces working?

Comment: The INSPIRE example workspace was removed from the download since it was not maintained and outdated. Please check issue https://github.com/deegree/deegree3/issues/1571 for more informationl